# Jquery animation - div jumps?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a robot image that I'm trying to move to the left, off screen, with JQuery. 
The div is positioned like so:

```
#robot{
   position:fixed;
   margin-left:800px;
   bottom:-40px;
}
```

So, it's basically at middle bottom. Then I animate:

```
$('#robot').animate({left:"-=1000px"},12000,"linear", stopRobotTimer);
```

It works, however as soon as the animate begins, the robot jumps about `200 pixels left` and then begins the 12sec animation.

Comment: Look to see if you have a padding/margin that's getting in the way.  Check out this article for more on this specific type of issue: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/animation-jump-quick-tip/.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the expected end point literally?

```
$('#robot').animate({left:"-200px"},12000,"linear", stopRobotTimer);
```

you do -= which should just result in -200 in this case since it is defined in your css.

**EDIT**

My mistake - I forgot to mention you either should change your css delclaration to left:800px; OR change your animate statement to be:

$('#robot').animate({marginLeft:"-200px"},12000,"linear", stopRobotTimer);

cause initially your css does not specify "left" it instead specified "margin-left"

Answer (score 0):

When you use `-=1000`, first you change the `left` then start animating. Try to change it like below

```
$('#robot').animate({left:"=-200px"},12000,"linear", stopRobotTimer);
```